# Would it be right to create multiple docker containers for databases in a multi-tenant application?

Tags: mysql, docker, multi-tenant

I am building an application that is going to have huge amounts of data for every single client. This is an accounting application. So having a single db for all client’s won’t suffice since every company/client will have huge amount of transactions.  I am using mysql as the database.

Every client gets its own db so that data fetched is fast, secure and only that client can access it.
But to implement this on docker, should i create an individual container of mysql for every client or just one container for mysql and create individual dbs in them ?

Comment: You might think about how this will scale to more than a couple of clients: either way it will be an administrative hassle to set up a new client.  If you can't fit this into a single MySQL database then a different database technology might be required.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Which DB would you suggest? I am using mysql because i need transactions, rollbacks and relationships. Is there any better option out there?